# Fixing Date, Time and Timer On Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, typescript

Zero experience with javascript. As part of an assignment, i've been told to build an app that displays, date, time and also a timer in which the user could make an input.

I successfully with google, created each app and they work great individually.
However when i join them together (they are supposed to display on one page) i get the following problems.

1. the timer doesn't work. If i comment out the code for the digital clock, timer would work. I can't seem to figure out a way to have both the the time and the clock running concurrently...
2. date just won't display on the page ...

MEANWHILE ON CODEPEN, IT WORKS PERFECT

THE HTML

```
<body onload="tellTime()" onload="tellDate()" onload="todaysDate()">

<!--html for clock-->
<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock"></div>

<!--html for date-->
<div id="show"></div>

<!---html for timer--->
<h1><span>Timer</span></h1>

<div id="canvas" class="container group">
    <div id="primaryContent" class="group">
        <p>Input The Time In Minutes And Click Start</p>
        <div id="inputArea">
            <input type="text" id="minutes"> <input type="button" value="Start" id="myButton" onclick="startCounter()">
        </div>
        <h2 id="time">0:00</h2>
    </div>  
</div>
```

THE CSS

```
/* Google font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron');
body {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #17D4FE;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
}
.clock {
  font-size: 60px;
}
#show {
    font-size: 60px;
}
#minutes {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#myButton {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

THE JS

```
//code for digital clock
function tellTime() {
    let date = new Date();
    let h = date.getHours();
    let m = date.getMinutes();
    let s = date.getSeconds();
    let session = "AM";

    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }

    if(h > 12){
        h = h - 12;
        session = "PM";
    }

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    let time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    
    setTimeout(tellTime, 1000);
}
tellTime();


//code for date
function todaysDate() {
    let today = new Date();
    let cDay = today.getDate();
    let cMonth = today.getMonth();
    let cYear = today.getFullYear();
    let calender = cDay + '/' + cMonth + '/' + cYear;
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = calender;
}
todaysDate();


//code for timer
let mySeconds;
let intervalHandle;

function resetPage(){
    document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display="none";  
}

function tick() {
    let timeDisplay = document.getElementById("time");
    let min = Math.floor(mySeconds/60);
    let sec = mySeconds-(min*60);

    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    let message = min.toString() + ":" + sec;
    timeDisplay.innerHTML=message;

    if (mySeconds === 0) {
        alert("Buzz Buzz");
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    }

    mySeconds--;
}

function startCounter() {
    let myInput = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
    if (isNaN(myInput)){
        alert("Type a valid number please");
        return;
    }
    mySeconds=myInput*60;
    
    intervalHandle=setInterval(tick, 1000);
    
    document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display="none";
    
}

window.onload=function(){   
    function myFunction(){
        startCounter(); 
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Are there any JS errors in your console?

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code in https://jsfiddle.net
IT works, date is tickt and timer works.. at the end I got Buzz buzz.
May you explain, what exactly does not work?

Comment: Check for errors in your browser dev tools console ( F12 )

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at tellTime (app.js:23)
    at app.js:27"

"Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mySeconds' before initialization
    at startCounter (app.js:76)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:25)"

Those are the two errors i found when i checked. Currently googling how to fix but any help would be appreciated. @disinfor

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using moment JS? I would look into it. Instead of re-creating the wheel you have a library that can do a lot of the work for you. Go to: [MomentJS ][1]

This is how it would work. Copy and paste this (below) into the bottom of your html page, and above the `<body>`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/x.y.z/moment.min.js"></script>
```

That will reference the library without you having to download it. Then from there you can use the moment functions like this:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // June 21st 2020, 6:28:24 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Sunday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jun 21st 20
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2020 escaped 2020
moment().format();
```

However there is much more you can do , more specifically to your needs. Take a look at the website

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any libraries. My instructor insists i must learn vanilla js to a certain extent before i start using libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
I just needed to remove my JS source file from the html head element and put it at the ending of the body element.
Something about JS loading before html dom was causing it to break.
Its working on browser now.